# From flat to nested object recursively javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, javascript-objects

I have a flat array of objects :

```
let x = [
   {parentKeyid: null,children:[]},
   {parentKeyid: 0,   children:[]},
   {parentKeyid: 1,   children:[]}
];
```

and i want to make from this to the array of nested objects:

```
const res = [{
  parentKeyid: null, 
  children: [{ 
      parentKeyid: 0,
      children:[{
        parentKeyid: 1, 
        children:[] 
      }]
  }]
}]
```

Here is my code:

```js
let x = [{
  parentKeyid: null,
  children:[]
},
{
  parentKeyid: 0,
  children:[]
},
{
  parentKeyid: 1,
  children:[]
}];

function recursively(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        let objToReturn = {
            parentKeyid: arr[0].parentKeyid,
            children: arr[0].children
        }
        return objToReturn
    }
    let transformedArr = arr.splice(0,1);
    transformedArr[0].children.push(recursively(arr));
    return transformedArr
}
let stringified = JSON.stringify(recursively(x), null, ' ');
console.log(stringified)
```

as you see i almost getting what i want but i can't figure out how to push an object into the children property without arr

Comment: "*almost getting what i want*" - the snippet you posted seems to work. How is the result you're getting wrong?

Comment: in your data `id` is missing. you have only the parent id and no other reference.

Comment: @Bergi in my object where parentKeyId has null property my children property is
[[obj]], i need [obj], if my array of obj gets wider i wil be getting [[]] instead of []

Comment: Oh, right. I think you're looking for `return transformedArr[0]` then.

Comment: Or rather do `const objToReturn = arr.shift(); objToReturn.children.push(recursively(arr)); return objToReturn;` to make it more clear that you don't want a "transformed list" but really just the first element of the array.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, good solution too, more beautiful than mine with a lot of [0].))
Thank you !

Comment: I'm really curious about your input structure.  Shouldn't those nodes have `id`s as well as `parentKeyId`s?  If they do, then there are a number of answers around that can easily be modified to solve this.  As it stands, it seems that you are explicitly pointing to something that is only implicitly specified (the object index) and that is very fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you already have an array where you can access each element directly, you don't need a recursive solution. Also your current solution doesn't actually take into account the `parentKeyid`, it just transforms the array into a nested list. I think what you're really looking for is

```js
const x = [
   {parentKeyid: null,children:[]},
   {parentKeyid: 0,   children:[]},
   {parentKeyid: 1,   children:[]},
   {parentKeyid: 0,   children:[]},
   {parentKeyid: 2,   children:[]},
   {parentKeyid: 1,   children:[]},
];

const roots = [];
for (const el of x) {
    if (el.parentKeyid == null) {
        roots.push(el);
    } else {
        x[el.parentKeyid].children.push(el);
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(roots, null, ' '));
```

Comment: Recursive solution is more suitable for me. I wanted to create a nested list but your hint in comments helped me.